# Is it possible to prevent headers to send again?

Tags: php, iframe, header, include

imagine this:

```
<?php
include_once('galeria.php');
?>
```

the galeria.php file is a complete html/php file.
Is it possible to include the file and prevent headers to send again?
I just don't want to use iframe or change my include files.

Comment: this will do it self..

Comment: the head section of the galleria.php will be loading again right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers are sent only once - right before the first bytes are sent to the browser. The bytes can be sent to the browser by (for example) `echo()`, `print()`, or by literal text/html outside the `<?php ?>` sections.

If your file which is including the `galeria.php` does not need to send any headers *explicitely*, then you have nothing to worry about.

Otherwise - if your file which is including the `galeria.php` *needs* to send headers explicitely, you may buffer the output of `galeria.php` as follows:

- First, call `ob_start()` (redirects all the output to a temporary buffer),
- Then include `galeria.php` (output gets sent to the buffer, not to browser. Headers are *not* sent yet),
- Then send the headers as you need via `header()`,
- Call `ob_end_flush()` to send the buffer contents to the browser (and all the default headers with it).

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 2):

You have confused everyone by using the term "headers". Headers is what is sent by the web server to tell the browser what to do with the payload. You are talking about the HEAD and I suspect HTML and BODY tags.

Well any sensible person would simply split the files up into section, but for some strange reason (you haven't told us why) you state that you do not wish to do this. In that case you can read in the galeria.php file and use either PHP's DOM class methods (preferred) or some REGEX (less good) to extract the body payload from the galeria.php file.

Can you tell us why you do not want to design this sensibly?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :-) to manny files and the files I'm including serve another propose so I can't change them.
Interesting the PHP DOM class method

Answer (score 1):

**include_once**

> The `include_once` statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the `include` statement, with the only difference being that **if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again.** As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

**[`Official Document`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)**

Comment: but the main file has already load is own head section, the galleria.php file has another head section and will be load with include_once('galleria.php')